# Images dissapear after reloading JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I'm coding a website where you can upload images and I want them to stay stored in localstorage so I can refresh the screen and the images won't be deleted. I have two versions of the code.

JavaScript where I can only store 1 key:

```
function refresh() {
    window.location.reload();
}

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    for (var i = 0, f; (f = files[i]); i++) {
        // Only process image files.
        if (!f.type.match("image.*")) {
            continue;
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();


        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                // Render thumbnail.
                var span = document.createElement("span");
                span.innerHTML = ['<img class="image" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join("");
                document.getElementById("list").insertBefore(span, null);
                localStorage.setItem('img', e.target.result);
            };
        })(f);
        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}
document.getElementById("upload-button").addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);

if (localStorage.img) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML += ['<img class="img" src="', localStorage.img, '" title=""/>'].join("");
    document.getElementById("list").insertBefore(span, null);
}
```

Javascript code where I can have multiple keys but they dissapear from the screen even tho the keys are in localstorage:

```
function refresh() {
  window.location.reload();
}

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  for (var i = 0, f; (f = files[i]); i++) {
    // Only process image files.
    if (!f.type.match("image.*")) {
      continue;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var counter = 0;

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
      return function (e) {
        // Render thumbnail.
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = [
          '<img class="image" src="',
          e.target.result,
          '" title="',
          escape(theFile.name),
          '"/>'
        ].join("");
        document.getElementById("list").insertBefore(span, null);
        counter++;
        var suma = "img" + counter;
        localStorage.setItem(suma, e.target.result);
      };
    })(f);
    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}
document
  .getElementById("upload-button")
  .addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);

if (localStorage.suma) {
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.innerHTML += [
    '<img class="img" src="',
    localStorage.suma,
    '" title=""/>'
  ].join("");
  document.getElementById("list").insertBefore(span, null);
}
```

You can check the full code here:

OneKey: https://codepen.io/rickypcyt/pen/xxWdgmy

MultipleKeys: https://codepen.io/rickypcyt/pen/RwMYZMw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your multi-key example, you are setting suma to contain "img" + i which means the key for each image will be "img1","img2" etc.

So you will need to do something like loop through localStorage:

```
Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function(key){
  let imgURL = localStorage.getItem(key);
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.innerHTML += [
    '<img class="img" src="',
    imgURL,
    '" title=""/>'
  ].join("");
  document.getElementById("list").insertBefore(span, null);
})
```